# php codeigniter count rows

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter, I want to count all rows from database table but the query dose not retrieve the exact total of rows.
Here is Model

```
public function countRow(){
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT *,count(id) AS num_of_time FROM home");
    // print_r($query->result());
    return $query->result();
}
```

and this is the controller

```
public function countTotalrow(){
     $data['query'] = $this->home_model->countRow(); 
}
```

this is the view

```
foreach ($num_of_time as $row){
    <span><?php print_r($row->id);?></span>
```

Comment: if it does not get the exact total of rows, what does it retrieve?

Comment: i think the variable '$num_of_time' in the third code sample should be '$query'

Comment: it give an incorrect number 11, but the records are 14 in table.

Comment: try replacing this "print_r($row->id)" with this "print_r($row->num_of_time)"

Comment: not working when i changed "print_r($row->id)" to  "print_r($row->num_of_time)" it gets 21 .

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You could use the helper function `$query->num_rows()`

It returns the number of rows returned by the query. You can use like this:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM my_table');
echo $query->num_rows();
```

Comment: There is no reason to run a full query when the database engine can just return the total row count from it's metadata storage. It is resource wasteful and won't scale well. Instead of querying the whole table, use `$this->db->count_all_results()`

Comment: yes i am agree with  @pbarney .there is no need to fire full query because you can get record from 
$this->db->from('home');
$this->db->count_all_results();
source : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results

Comment: Not only is this inefficient, but it also produces the **wrong** result with certain database drivers (PDO/SQLite and possibly others will give you the wrong result)

Answer (score 27):

Use this code:

`$this->db->where(['id'=>2])->from("table name")->count_all_results();`

or

`$this->db->from("table name")->count_all_results();`

Answer (score 5):

You may try this one

```
    $this->db->where('field1',$filed1);
    $this->db->where('filed2',$filed2);
    $result = $this->db->get('table_name')->num_rows();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to count all rows. You can use this in model function:

```
$this->db->select('count(*)');
$query = $this->db->get('home');
$cnt = $query->row_array();
return $cnt['count(*)'];
```

It returns single value, that is row count

Answer (score 2):

This is what is did that solved the same problem. I solved it by creating a function that returns the query result thus:

```
function getUsers(){
$query = $this->db->get('users');
return $query->result();
}
```

//The above code can go in the user_model or whatever your model is.

This allows me to use one function for the result and number of returned rows.

Use this code below in your contoller where you need the count as well as the result array().

```
//This gives you the user count using the count function which returns and integer of the exact rows returned from the query.
$this->data['user_count'] = count($this->user_model->getUsers());

//This gives you the returned result array.
$this->data['users'] = $this->user_model->getUsers();
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function record_count() {
   return $this->db->count_all("tablename");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

replace the query inside your model function with this

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM home");
```

in view:

```
echo $query->num_rows();
```

Comment: it gives this error   A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @nilab dont include foreach, just the echo

Comment: not working it shows wrong number @Kelvin Barsana i need the total entries of my table which are 14 it give me 21 after removing foreach.

Comment: model:   $query = $this->db->query('SELECT id FROM idea_home');
  return $query; view:   <span><?php echo $query->num_rows();?></span>

Comment: num_rows() displays how many rows have been fetched, so its kinda weird to see different results, how about changing the query to 'SELECT *'

Answer (score 1):

**To count all rows in a table:**

**Controller:**

```
function id_cont() {
   $news_data = new news_model();
   $ids=$news_data->data_model();
   print_r($ids);
}
```

**Model:**

```
function data_model() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('news_data');
    $id = $this->db->get()->num_rows();
    return $id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function number_row()
 {
    $query = $this->db->select("count(user_details.id) as number")
                       ->get('user_details');              
      if($query-> num_rows()>0)
      {
          return $query->row();
      } 
      else
      {
          return false;
      } 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :) 
I created my on model of count all results

in library_model

```
function count_all_results($column_name = array(),$where=array(), $table_name = array())
{
        $this->db->select($column_name);
        // If Where is not NULL
        if(!empty($where) && count($where) > 0 )
        {
            $this->db->where($where);
        }
        // Return Count Column
        return $this->db->count_all_results($table_name[0]);//table_name array sub 0
}
```

Your Controller will look like this

```
public function my_method()
{
  $data = array(
     $countall = $this->model->your_method_model()
  );
   $this->load->view('page',$data);
}
```

Then Simple Call The Library Model  In Your Model

```
function your_method_model()
{
        return $this->library_model->count_all_results(
               ['id'],
               ['where],
               ['table name']
           );
}
```