# how to count id and shows in tables

Tags: codeigniter, count

[how count all id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5Xph.png)

my model

```
public function bobot()
{
    $this->db->select('nama_kriteria,bobot, count(id_kriteria) as jumlah');
    $this->db->from('tb_kriteria');
    $this->db->group_by('id_kriteria');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

I want count all rows and show in views but when I count only counts one in each row

Comment: please check this same topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958307/php-codeigniter-count-rows/28958771

Answer (score 0):

return $this->db->count_all_results('tb_kriteria');